# Php parse html dom and count specific rows

Tags: php, parsing, dom, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm using the "**Simple php DOM Parser**" to parse an html table and count its row.

I solved to count all the rows (tr) in it with this code:

```
$rows = $table->find('.trClass');
$count = count($rows);
echo $count;
```

And I correctly get the number of all the rows in the table.

Now I want to count only the rows which contains a specific **td** (with a specific string). 
We could assume that I want to count only the rows with this td:

```
<td class="tdClass" align="center" nowrap="">TARGET STRING</td>
```

How can I modify the first code to match this scope?
I tried to use "preg_match" or "preg_match_all" but I don't have much experience in it, so I miss the correct syntax..I think.

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
<?php
$targetString = 'TARGET STRING';
$rows = $table->find('.trClass');

$count = 0;
foreach($rows as $row) {
    foreach($row->find('td') as $td) {
        if ($td->innertext === $targetString) {
            $count++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but an error displays me with your code: "syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in", referring to the "foreach($row->('td') as $td) {" line..

Comment: Ok, I found out the solution for the error (you missed "find") and now it works great! Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Yeah sorry, I missed that one. Something clearly went wrong with the copy paste :). Fixed it also in the code now.

Comment: Don't worry and thanks again. Now I'm facing a stronger challenge regarding this. You can find the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453380/php-parsed-html-table-and-count-specific-td-similar-to-another

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look at it. Actually, it is not much of a stronger challenge.

Answer (score 0):

```
$target = 'TARGET STRING';

$n_matchingrows = 0;

$rows = $table->find('tr.trClass');
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $cell = $row->find('td.tdClass[align=center][nowrap=""]', 0);
    if ($cell and $cell->innertext===$target) {
       $n_matchingrows += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Small mistake in this approach, if a TR has multiple TD's with the target string, your count will be wrong ;).

Comment: To answer your doubt, the target string could be contained only one time in each matching row (only one TD's target string for matching row)