# passing Javascript variable to PHP on form submission

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html, forms

This question follows from my previous question [counting the rows in html table using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497606/counting-the-rows-in-html-table-using-php).
Since I got no working solution, I want to try a new way but dont know how to implement it.
I assign unique ID to each dynamic row added using Javascript. So the count variable in Javascript stores the number of rows present in HTML table. When i submit the form, it is processed by `savedata.php`. Is it possible to automatically pass the Javascript variable count to `savedata.php` each time the form is submitted.

Following is a short version of my Javascript file that is used to create unique IDs for elements of dynamically created rows.

```
var count=2;

function addRow()
{


var table=document.getElementById("studenttable");
var row=table.insertRow(-1);
var cell15=row.insertCell(14);

var ipt8 = document.createElement('input');
    ipt8.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    ipt8.id = "text" + count; 
    ipt8.name = "htmlrow[]";      
    ipt8.value = count;        
    cell15.appendChild(ipt8);
count++;
}
```

Each time a new row is added, count increments, so just passing it to the PHP file will allow to get the number of rows in HTML table. I want to do it automatically each time the form is submitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this inside your form..

```
<input name="NumRows" id="NumRows" type="hidden" value="0"/>
```

And then modify your JS to update the value...

```
document.getElementById("NumRows").value = count;
```

Then, in your PHP you can do...

```
$NumRows = $_REQUEST['NumRows'];
```

Note that if for some reason `NumRows` isn't passed with the form (unlikely here but possible elsewhere) then you should do this in PHP...

```
$NumRows = isset($_REQUEST['NumRows'])?$_REQUEST['NumRows']:0;
```

Which means "If `$_REQUEST['NumRows']` is set, use it, otherwise set `$NumRows` to 0"

Comment: I need not add this input field to each row. Right ?

Comment: Thanx a lot. Finally done. I was wondering how could I do it without ajax and you have found me a perfect solution. Thanx again.

Comment: Nope - once per form :) And you're very welcome, always nice to see new members here - hopefully we'll see you around more

Comment: Yup, looking forward to gain experience and help out other fellows as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest never use $_REQUEST, use $_POST for post method forms. If you use $_REQUEST you have no guarantee that the data came from the post data, which leads to security holes in your script. So better use

```
$NumRows = $_POST['NumRows'];
```

to access the count value in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Go for Ajax call. Each time when submit button is clicked make an ajax call and send the required data to the any php page.

here go through these links and they will definitely gonna help u

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/